# sqlite database multiple tables

Tags: android, sqlite

So I have a scenario I am making an Android app for attendance management. 
I want to save all the records in an SQLite database. Like my app will allow the user to add the names of the students of a class. Secondly, my app is also able to store attendance data for multiple classes like a record for B.tech 
CSEsem1 , sem2 and so on. 
So I thought the following idea:

I will create a main table which will be having the names of records in `col1`, its corresponding table name for students names and in `col3` I will be having the corresponding table name for attendance data.

```
col1(Records name)      col2(names Table)      col3(attendance Table)
B.tech CSE              CSE-students           CSE-attendance       
B.tech ECE              ECE-students           ECE-attendance
```

Basically I will be creating two table per record.
But I don't think this way is good.
Please tell me is it the right way or not?
If not, then please suggest me an another way of doing this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this:

You run one table for students:

```
@Entity(tableName = "students")
class Student {

  @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
  var id: Int = 0

  @ColumnInfo(name = "name")
  lateinit var type: String
}
```

And a table for attendance:

```
@Entity(
    tableName = "attendance",
    foreignKeys = [(ForeignKey(
        entity = Student::class,
        onDelete = ForeignKey.CASCADE,
        parentColumns = arrayOf("id"),
        childColumns = arrayOf("studentId")
    ))]
)
class Attendance {

  @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
  var id: Int = 0

  @ColumnInfo(name = "date")
  lateinit var type: String

  @ColumnInfo(name = "class")
  lateinit var type: String

  @ColumnInfo(name = "studentId")
  lateinit var type: Int
}
```

Usage:

```
@Dao
interface AttendanceDao {

  @get:Query("SELECT * FROM attendance WHERE studentId = :studentId")
  fun attendance(studentId: Int): Single<List<Attendance>>

  @get:Query("SELECT students.name FROM attendance INNER JOIN students ON students.id == attendance.studentId WHERE date = :day AND class = :class")
  fun attendance(day: String, class: String): Single<List<String>>

  // ...
}
```

Comment: Creating two tables for each class is not SQL way. You can store attendance data for each class in one table. The same thing with enrollment. You can store the data in one table. So you only need three tables. (I'll correct my code to account for enrollment.)

Comment: The post becomes too long and cannot be submitted. But you get the idea: add one table with columns `studentId` and `class`. The three tables will be sufficient for your needs.

Comment: your code haven't helped but i got an idea from your suggestion that i need three tables i have made three tables one for attendance one for names  and one for the class and have made respective foreign keys to relate them thanks i'll upvote your answer